# How to go back to DispatchQueue.main from URLSession.shared.dataTask (macOS framework)

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, urlsession

I'm building a macOS framework and at some point, I need to make a request to some API

When I got the response I want to update the UI. I'm using URLSession.shared.dataTask to make the call and as I know the call is made in the background thread

For some reason when I try to go back to the main thread nothing happens

I'm using a virtual machine to run my framework

Any help?
Thanks

Here how I doing the request:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  if error != nil {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //Display error message on the UI
      //This never happens
      //Never go back to the main thread
      //Framework stop working
    }
  }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this wasn't working? I'm having problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your task is called?

```
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

....

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(nil, nil)
    }
}
dataTask.resume() // You should add this.
```

Comment: Yes it 's. I omitted it from code but I already updated it @A. Amini